# How do I use JFrog CLI with CircleCI 2.0?

Tags: jfrog-cli, circleci-2.0

I'm trying to use JFrog CLI with CircleCI 2.0 to publish my docker image into my JFrog artifactory, after some research I've found this tutorial: https://circleci.com/docs/1.0/Artifactory/ but it's based on CircleCI 1.0 specification.

my `config.yml` file currently is:

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: docker:17.05.0-ce-git
    steps:
      - checkout
      - setup_remote_docker
      - run:
          name: Install dependencies
          command: |
            apk add --no-cache \
              py-pip=9.0.0-r1
            pip install \
              docker-compose==1.12.0 \
              awscli==1.11.76
      - run:
          name: Setup JFrog
          command: |
            wget http://dl.bintray.com/jfrog/jfrog-cli-go/1.7.1/jfrog-cli-linux-amd64/jfrog
            chmod +x jfrog
            ./jfrog rt config --url $ARTIFACTORY_URL --user $ARTIFACTORY_USER --apikey $ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD
            docker login -e $ARTIFACTORY_EMAIL -u $ARTIFACTORY_USER -p $ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD $ARTIFACTORY_DOCKER_REPOSITORY
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
#!/bin/sh -eo pipefail
wget http://dl.bintray.com/jfrog/jfrog-cli-go/1.7.1/jfrog-cli-linux-amd64/jfrog
chmod +x jfrog
./jfrog rt config --url $ARTIFACTORY_URL --user $ARTIFACTORY_USER --apikey $ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD
docker login -e $ARTIFACTORY_EMAIL -u $ARTIFACTORY_USER -p $ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD $ARTIFACTORY_DOCKER_REPOSITORY
Connecting to dl.bintray.com (35.162.24.14:80)
Connecting to akamai.bintray.com (23.46.57.209:80)

jfrog                100% |*******************************|  9543k  0:00:00 ETA
/bin/sh: ./jfrog: not found
Exited with code 127
```

Does anyone know what is the correct way to use JFrog CLI with CircleCI 2.0?

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed this installing JFrog CLI through npm:

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: docker:17.05.0-ce-git
    steps:
      - checkout
      - setup_remote_docker
      - run:
          name: Install dependencies
          command: |
            apk add --no-cache \
              py-pip=9.0.0-r1 \
              openssl \
              nodejs
            pip install \
              docker-compose==1.12.0 \
              awscli==1.11.76
      - run:
          name: Setup JFrog
          command: |
            npm install -g jfrog-cli-go
            jfrog rt config --url $ARTIFACTORY_URL --user $ARTIFACTORY_USER --apikey $ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD
            docker login -u $ARTIFACTORY_USER -p $ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD $ARTIFACTORY_DOCKER_REPOSITORY
```

Now it's working.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to installing with Node.js (which is perfectly possible too, especially if you're running a Node.js build in CircleCI), you can use a cURL command to install it for you.

```
curl -fL https://getcli.jfrog.io | sh
```

This script will download the latest released version of the JFrog CLI based on your operating system and your architecture (32 vs 64 bits).